# LINQ query finds subclass in an ObservableCollection of base class

Tags: .net, linq

I'm still getting my head around [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) queries and the LINQ extension methods.

Say I have a base class `BaseA` and subclass `SubB` with a property `IsAwesome`.  I have an `ObservableCollection<BaseA>`. Is there some neat way I can grab a collection of only SubB classes where IsAwesome is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
myCollection.Where(x => x is SubB && (x as SubB).IsAwesome);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or better:

```
myCollection.OfType<SubB>().Where(x => x.IsAwsome);
```